# Convert JSON file from flat to nested arrays in Azure Data Factory

Tags: arrays, json, azure, azure-data-factory

I'm trying to copy data from my Oracle DB into the Search Index and I'm using Azure Data Factory to copy data from oracle to Azure Blob Storage. 
How I can use it, to import data as nested JSON file.
At now, after query Oracle I get data like this:

```
[{"BOOKING_ID":1.0,"REFERENCES":"ABC00001","ROUTES":{"ROUTE":1.0,"DESTINATION":"Atlanta, USA","ORIGIN":"New York, USA"}}
,{"BOOKING_ID":2.0,"REFERENCES":"ABC00322","ROUTES":{"ROUTE":2.0,"DESTINATION":"Las Vegas, USA","ORIGIN":"Los Angeles, USA"}}
,{"BOOKING_ID":3.0,"REFERENCES":"ABC32322","ROUTES":{"ROUTE":3.0,"DESTINATION":"Berlin, GER","ORIGIN":"Moscow, RUS"}}
,{"BOOKING_ID":4.0,"REFERENCES":"ABC543345","ROUTES":{"ROUTE":4.0,"DESTINATION":"Rome, ITA","ORIGIN":"Bejin, CHN"}}
,{"BOOKING_ID":5.0,"REFERENCES":"ABC51145","ROUTES":{"ROUTE":5.0,"DESTINATION":"Warsaw, POL","ORIGIN":"Copenhagen, DEN"}}
,{"BOOKING_ID":5.0,"REFERENCES":"ABC51145","ROUTES":{"ROUTE":6.0,"DESTINATION":"Copenhaged, DEN","ORIGIN":"Paris, FRA"}}
,{"BOOKING_ID":5.0,"REFERENCES":"ABC51145","ROUTES":{"ROUTE":7.0,"DESTINATION":"Paris, FRA","ORIGIN":"Madrid, ESP"}}
]
```

but I need data like this:

```
[
  {
    "BOOKING_ID": 1.0,
    "REFERENCES": "ABC00001",
    "ROUTES": [
      {
        "ROUTE": 1.0,
        "DESTINATION": "Atlanta, USA",
        "ORIGIN": "New York, USA"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "BOOKING_ID": 2.0,
    "REFERENCES": "ABC00322",
    "ROUTES": [
      {
        "ROUTE": 2.0,
        "DESTINATION": "Las Vegas, USA",
        "ORIGIN": "Los Angeles, USA"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "BOOKING_ID": 3.0,
    "REFERENCES": "ABC32322",
    "ROUTES": [
      {
        "ROUTE": 3.0,
        "DESTINATION": "Berlin, GER",
        "ORIGIN": "Moscow, RUS"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "BOOKING_ID": 4.0,
    "REFERENCES": "ABC543345",
    "ROUTES": [
      {
        "ROUTE": 4.0,
        "DESTINATION": "Rome, ITA",
        "ORIGIN": "Bejin, CHN"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "BOOKING_ID": 5.0,
    "REFERENCES": "ABC51145",
    "ROUTES": [
      {
        "ROUTE": 5.0,
        "DESTINATION": "Warsaw, POL",
        "ORIGIN": "Copenhagen, DEN"
      },
      {
        "ROUTE": 6.0,
        "DESTINATION": "Copenhaged, DEN",
        "ORIGIN": "Paris, FRA"
      },
      {
        "ROUTE": 7.0,
        "DESTINATION": "Paris, FRA",
        "ORIGIN": "Madrid, ESP"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

**UPDATE**
I use Azure Functions with lodash, but now I'm trying to receive the JSON from Azure Blob Storage. Problem is, what when I try to read the JSON, I have results like this:

```
"type": "Buffer",
    "data": [
        239,
        187,
        191,
        91,
        123,
...
```

and all data is in byte type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your requirement is group by the `BOOKING_ID`, merge the `ROUTES` object into one array. It can't be implemented in the copy activity directly.

Two ideas:

1.Using [Web Activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-web-activity) + [Azure Function Activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-azure-function-activity).

In the Web Activity,encapsulate query methods into REST API and return the flat json data.Pass the output of Web Activity into Azure Function Activity. In the Azure Function method,loop the array json data into nested arrays following your needs then configure the output of Azure Function as Azure Blob Storage.(Please refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob))

2.Using [Custom Activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/transform-data-using-dotnet-custom-activity).

You could execute scripts in the Azure Batch Job rely on VM. Such as you could use [cx-Oracle](https://oracle.github.io/python-cx_Oracle/) package to query the json data order by the BOOKING_ID,then using python code to loop the result and convert it following your needs.